# Preg_Match Error To Get Line

Tags: php, syntax, comments, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
if(preg_match("//*/i",$line))echo "comment start";
if(preg_match("/*//i",$line))echo "comment end";
```

I'm searching comments which one starts with `/*` and end with `*/` and I cant get any result with this code. I’m trying to get comment start and end line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$line = '/* Hello, world! This is a comment! */';

if (preg_match("/^\/\*(.*)/i", $line)) echo "comment start";
if (preg_match("/(.*)\*\/$/i", $line)) echo "comment end";
```

You need to escape out slashes like `/` with a `\` preceding it. Otherwise it’s interpreted as part of the regex logic & not something you are looking for.  But that said, unclear what you want to get out of matching the beginning & ending parts of the comment.

Comment: Your code is now correct. But it wasn't before I informed you :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 if (preg_match('/\\\\\*/i', $line)) echo "comment start";  
 if (preg_match('%\*/%i', $line)) echo "comment end";
```